# c++ extracting two quotes from a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a string

> "John" "Hello there"

I'm looking to extract the quotes into two strings so that I can categorize them like.

```
User: John 
Text: Hello there
```

I was wondering what the best way to do this is? Is there a string function that can be applied to make this an easy process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to split a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string)

Comment: uhm, define 'easy' ... the question is a little vague ... there are gazilion ways of doing it, with gaziliion possible requirements ...

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::quoted`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b088af18709f876d)</kbd>**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string user, text;

    std::istringstream iss("\"John\" \"Hello there\"");

    if (iss >> std::quoted(user) >> std::quoted(text)) {
        std::cout << "User: " << user << "\n";
        std::cout << "Text: " << text << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note it also supports escaping quotes: if the input is `Me "This is a \"quoted\" word"`, it will print (also **<kbd>[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee0baa9c6bc64747)</kbd>**)

```
User: Me
Text: This is a "quoted" word
```

Comment: Added live demos

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution that uses `stringstream`:

```
  std::string name = "\"Jhon\" \"Hello There\"";
  std::stringstream ss{name};
  std::string token;

  getline(ss, token, '\"');
  while (!ss.eof())
  {
      getline(ss, token, '\"');
      ss.ignore(256, '\"');

      std::cout << token << std::endl;
  }
```

Output:

```
Jhon
Hello There
```